# Ruby on Rails Can't update user "points" using simple button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

So basically Im trying to put in my webapp a button that calls a POST link that when clicked activates an "addpoints" method, that adds (you guessed right) points to the current user.
It seems to work fine if I call the current_user instance but when I call the current_user.points it returns 0 as if it didnt save in the database.
Any idea why this happens? It should be a simple thing, so I'm feeling pretty dumb right now, maybe you guys can help me.

Thank you for you time and help!
p.s. if you need more information just ask

here's the method in question:

```
  def addpoints
    @user = current_user
    current_user.winpoints += 10
    current_user.save

    redirect_to users
  end
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not links to images of text. It's unclear what specific sequence events you're discussing or what you expect to see at what point. You may just need to reload the current user in the console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Ill try and be more specific:
I have a user, instance with points that has default value of 0.
I want to click a button to turn that value to 10, and to show it in the user show page.
Even tho in the instance the value goes up to ten, when I call the specific value is still is 0.
How do I just reload the current user in the console so that the value is shown in he user?
Thank you again

Comment: Like @DaveNewton said, you probably need to reload the user in the console.  Stop and restart the console, then query for that user again.  Or try `reload!` in the console and query the user again.  Or just requery for the user and check their points.

Comment: What if I wanted it to make it work in rails s, and not in the console, is there a way to fix my code and make it work without the reload part?
Is it something wrong with the database, is it the user controller, the user model?

Comment: In the rails console you may have to re instantiate the user for the updated values.  In the Rails application itself, the `redirect_to users` part will redirect the page and requery all the users.  If you are displaying the points values on that page, you should see an updated value because you reloaded the page.  You just have to display `user.points`.